# Need help aligning an hr with body text of posts

Tags: html, css, tumblr

On my website, I put a horizontal rule in between my posts, but I can't seem to get it to actually line up *with* the posts, that is: to make its center lined up with the center of text of the posts -  it is just in the center of the page.

http://kylesethgray.com

Comment: You can put hr inside .post div?

Answer (score 0):

Having `margin : 0` on your `hr`will align it to the left. You can then adjust the width to align it with the text.